# Is it possible to search for bibtex citations in Lyx

Tags: bibtex, lyx

In LyX, is it possible to search for a citation I've already inserted by BibTex key? I'm inserting references from a BibTex file using Insert -> Citation.

For example, I would like to find all the locations in the text where I've already added "Smith 2012".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select Document --> Outline, and in the panel that pops up on the left side choose *List of citations* from the drop-down menu. You can filter the list to show only some labels.

[image][image]

Comment: In Lyx version 2.1.2, the document outline is accessible under `View / Outline Pane`.